# How can I process multiple parameters in a method like NSLog?

Tags: objective-c

This has been asked before, but I dont get my head around this. I have my own onscreen Logger and it has a method "append" that should work pretty much as NSLog, taking multiple parameters.

So instead of writing this :

```
int mynum = 19;
NSLog(@"This is a number %d",mynum);
```

I want to do this :

```
[Logger append:@"This is a number %d",mynum];
```

Any idea how i could do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, here's the hard way. :-)

Use the stdarg.h macros to create a va_list copy of your additional arguments, then create a string with that, using the `-initWithFormat:arguments:` method:

```
-(void) append:(NSString*)format, ... {
    va_list args, args_copy;
    va_start(args, format);
    va_copy(args_copy, args);
    va_end(args);

    NSString *logString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format
                                                 arguments:args_copy];
    // Append logString to your logger

    va_end(args_copy);
    [logString release];
}
```

This way gives you all the flexibility of NSLog() itself, supporting any number and type of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You want an ellipsis, e.g.

```
-(SomeResult*)append:(id)object,... {
  id obj;
  va_list argumentList;
  va_start(argumentList, obj); 
  while (obj = va_arg(argumentList, id)) // Do something with obj
  va_end(argumentList);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Note, if you do simply want to do logging like you said @Terente solution is better

Comment: Close, but not quite. :-) Stdarg macros are the way to do this, but your example supports only object arguments, and requires a nil sentinel at the end of the argument list, rather than using the format string. You're also not using va_start() quite right - it should be `va_start(argumentList, object)`.

Comment: @Sherm, good point, in my defence I was just providing a introduction to using variadic functions and certainly not intending to produce some functional code. (+1 though for pointing this out)

Answer (score 0):

```
[Logger append:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is a number %d",mynum]];
```

Comment: well, yes, that would be the easy way ;) But since I am on the topic I really want to try the hard way.